# How are binary operations used in the real world?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary

Not necessarily a mathematical question, but how could binary operations be used in the real world? What applies to it?

Comment: Addition, subtraction, multiplication, division — all of these are binary operations.

Comment: And through the operations Brian said, many math operations can be done using them. Basically a binary operation is an operation made on two expressions (for instance, 1+1. + is a binary operations on two expressions 1 and 1)

Comment: I'm very aware of that.  So our everyday calculations, I.e., perhaps a contractor or accountant, could those serve as applications of binary operations?

Comment: Or maybe even C++ programming?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Can you please clarify?

Comment: If you add two numbers, that is a binary operation. I think that accountants frequently add numbers together. This is distinct from operating on *binary numbers* represented as $101110101$, etc. These are two different uses of the term binary.

Comment: Where are binary operations used besides the classroom

Comment: The question way too broad.

Comment: Any calculator, computer or any 3rd grade kid solving his math homework uses binary ops :). Agree with Martin

Answer (score 4):

A *binary operation* is any operation acting with two arguments, irrespective of the base, or indeed, whether they are numbers or not.

Adding two decimal numbers is a binary operation: $15 + 13 = 28$. Here, the addition operation takes two numbers, $15$ and $13$, and acts on them. In some notation systems, we can make this more clear by writing it as $(+\ 15\ 13) = 28$.

Multiplication is also a binary operation: $3\cdot 4 = 12$.

A unary operation takes a single argument. For example, differentiation is a unary operation: $\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\right) = 2x$.

The extension of these concepts can be brought beyond mathematics. For example, making a sandwich could be thought of as an order-5 operation:

$$S = \text{MakeSandwich}(\text{bread},\text{meat},\text{cheese},\text{veggies},\text{condiments}).$$

Indeed, if you so desired, you could define algebras on sandwiches!

Comment: The sandwich explanation LOL

Comment: @user58315 It may be tongue-in-cheek, but one of the real-world applications of abstract algebra is to abstract physical processes into mathematical concepts. This is relevant to fields such as manufacturing, etc. While no one would seriously consider an algebra on sandwiches, the same methods do become relevant when looking at real-world applications.

Comment: Alternatively, I might open a restaurant that charges customers more if the sandwich they order falls outside the group generated by the sandwiches on the menu.

Comment: I understand! Fees! Charges! Additional costs!